# Hyperledger-Fabric: What is the committer and orderer in core.yaml?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In `core.yaml`:

```
committer:
  enabled: true
  ledger:
    orderer: 127.0.0.1:5005
```

What is the concept of committer and orderer? I didn't hear about those in [Hyperledger-fabric docs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Do I have to write something about committer or orderer in docker-compose.yml? or.. Is it related in consensus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the terms **endorser** and **committer** defined in the Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 docs,

> The peers are diverged into two distinct roles – **Endorser** & **Committer**.
>   As an **endorser**, the peer will simulate the transaction and ensure that
>   the outcome is both deterministic and stable. As a **committer**, the peer
>   will validate the integrity of a transaction and then append to the
>   ledger.
>
> --[Hyperledger fabric docs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abstract_v1/#hyperledger-fabric-v10)

**orderer** is the address of the **ordering service** which is intended to provide an atomic broadcast ordering service for consumption by the peers. The ordering service is documented [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6f9b4272f4e3a6d843866402fa4325f39124e044/orderer/README.md)